# Distribute 20 black, 19 white balls distributed to 20 black and 19 white boxes.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

20 black, 19 white balls are distributed to 20 black and 19 white boxes such in a way that no boxes are empty. 
What is the probably that at least one white ball goes to a black box?

I think the solution is 
$ \frac{\binom{19}{1}*38!}{39!}$ since we choose 1 white ball and put it inside one of the black boxes. However I have problem. I am wondering if I can solve this question by subtracting every case of black going to black balls going to black boxes and white balls going to white boxes from all possible cases, but I couldn't find the formula for that.

Comment: There don't seem to be any red boxes.

Comment: Also, do we distinguish boxes of the same color?

Comment: I fixed it, I mixed a question with another one. We have only white and black boxes/balls

Comment: Isn't your "solution" a probability that is larger than 1?

Comment: Oh, you are right, then my solution is false too.

Comment: I fixed it I guess, I think after choosing a white ball it doesnt matter which black box we put it in I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $39\choose19$ ways to choose the boxes that the white balls go into.  Since there are also $19$ white boxes, there is only one of those ways that puts all of the white balls into the white boxes.  Therefore, the probability that at least one white balls goes into a black box is $$\frac{{39\choose19}-1}{39\choose19}$$

Comment: Why the sample space isnt "39!" ? Why don't we care for black balls at all? I thought when we talk about probably we should have think of every ball as distinct.

Comment: @70pr4k The black balls just go into the boxes that are empty after the white balls have been placed, so they are not independent factors in the problem.

Comment: I understand, thank you a lot! Have a nice day!